# htaccess rewriterule question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/mp/(.*)(/{0,1})$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/(.*)/mp/(.*)(/{0,1})$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3&$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory$ /main.php?id=0&il[lang]=$1 [L]
```

I use these lines and `localhost/showCategory/` is OK, `localhost/showCategory/0/1` is OK, 
`localhost/showCategory/0/2` stays on the first page...(same 0/1) not good 
What is the problem?

When I delete this `/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*` from the 3. and 4. line then it's OK,

but then is a problem with this URL: http://localhost/showCategory/627/prodaja-automobila

Comment: I guess you may remove parenthesis around (/{0,1}). And make sure you use back-references correctly (i mean numbers after $).

Comment: Please post  example urls that should be parsed, with all the variables and a sample value, something like
http://localhost/showCategory/627/prodaja-automobila/en/4/  >> showCategory.php?id=627&il[lang]=en&page=4 

also, an example with your /mp/ inside of it.

Comment: http://localhost/showCategory/44/auto-delovi_-oprema
array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(2) "44" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(0) "" } ["sh"]=>  &NULL }

http://localhost/en/showCategory/44/auto-delovi_-oprema
array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(2) "44" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(3) "en/" } ["sh"]=>  &NULL }

http://localhost/showCategory/590/transport/10
array(4) { ["id"]=>  string(3) "590" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(0) "" } ["page"]=>  string(2) "10" ["sh"]=>  &NULL } 
these are OK

Comment: http://localhost/showCategory/0/2
array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(1) "0" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(0) "" } ["sh"]=>  &NULL }

["page"]=> string(2) "10" is missing...

Comment: not in the comments please, edit your question. It's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your order is not correct as far as i can see: you should start with the rule involving the most variables, and end with the one with the least.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/(.*)/mp/(.*)(/{0,1})$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3&$4 [L]


RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]

#----------------------------
#Not sure this one is correct, if it is, it should be here i guess
#----------------------------
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/mp/(.*)(/{0,1})$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&$3 [L]



RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory$ /main.php?id=0&il[lang]=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the same problem...
var_dump($_GET) without this /[a-z\-_0-9\+]*
array(4) { ["id"]=>  string(1) "0" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(0) "" } ["page"]=>  string(1) "2" ["sh"]=>  &NULL } 

with:
array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(1) "0" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(0) "" } ["sh"]=>  &NULL }

Comment: things like this don't make sense: page=$3&$4  $4 will never be picked up

Comment: I use rewriterule for the first time
So what to do?

Comment: well: what are the variables that your script expects?

Comment: array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "0" ["il"]=> &array(1) { ["lang"]=> string(0) "" } ["page"]=> string(1) "2" ["sh"]=> &NULL }